# HtmlToImageConverter C# not properly generating image based on HTML/CSS

Tags: c#, html, css

For a Discord bot I am creating, I need to generate unique images for users' profiles. To do this, I am using the `NReco.ImageGenerator` package to convert the HTML and CSS into an image that the bot will generate, then put into chat.

My CSS/HTML designer and I have tried resizing and tweaking the image, but we think that `flexbox`, something he is using with the CSS, is causing issues.

Profile Command (with HTML and CSS included). Each `\n` character is what would normally be an `Enter` keystroke. This is simply so the program can read it.

```
[Command("profile")] //Generates a user's profile using HTML / CSS
        public async Task Profile()
        {
            var account = UserAccounts.GetAccount(Context.User);

            string css = "@font-face {\n  font-family: 'Raleway';\n  src: URL('Raleway-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');\n}\n\nhtml {\n    " +
                "\n    margin: 0px;\n    \n}\nbody {\n    \n    margin: 0px;\n    \n}\n\n#window {\n    \n    margin: 0px;\n    padding: 0;\n" +
                "    width: 300px;\n    height: 300px;\n    font-size: 15px;\n    padding: 0px;\n    font-family: 'Raleway';\n    \n}\n\n#header {\n" +
                "    \n    width: 100%;\n    height: 30%;\n    display: flex;\n    \n}\n\n#pfp {\n    \n    border: solid 3px black;\n    flex-grow: 1;\n" +
                "    \n}\n\n#userwindow {\n    \n    border: solid 3px black;\n    flex-grow: 0.352;\n    background-color: lightgrey;\n    margin-left: 5px;\n" +
                "    padding: 5px;\n    text-align: center;\n    \n}\n\n.reset.user {\n    \n    padding-bottom: 8px;\n    \n}\n\n#content {\n    \n    border: solid 3px black;\n" +
                "    background-color: lightgrey;\n    margin-top: 10px;\n    \n}\n\n#probox {\n    \n    height: 18px;\n    border: solid 1px white;\n    padding: 1px;\n" +
                "    margin-top: 10px;\n    margin-left: 10px;\n    margin-right: 10px;\n    \n}\n\n#probar {\n    \n    height: 100%;\n    width: 50%; /* " +
                "Insert EXP progress in percent here */\n" +
                "    background-color: #7FDCFF;\n    \n}\n\n#rows {\n    \n    display: flex;\n    padding-bottom: 10px;\n    \n}\n\n#exp {\n    \n    flex-grow: 1;\n    \n}\n\n#lvl {\n    \n    font-size: 25px;\n" +
                "    padding-left: 10px;\n    padding-right: 10px;\n    padding-top: 10px;\n    text-align: center;\n    \n}\n\n.reset.no {\n    \n    font-size: 45px;\n    \n}" +
                "\n\n#rep {\n    \n    text-align: center;\n    \n}\n\n#statsl {\n    \n    flex-grow: 1;\n    \n}\n\n#statsr {\n    \n    flex-grow: 1;\n    text-align: right;\n" +
                "    padding-right: 22px;\n    \n}\n\n#footer {\n    \n    display: flex;\n    border-top: solid black 2px;\n    padding: 10px;\n    width: 85%;\n    margin: auto;\n " +
                "       \n}\n\n#leftfoot {\n    \n    flex-grow: 1;\n    \n}\n\n#rightfoot {\n    \n    flex-grow: 1;\n    text-align: right;\n    \n}\n\n.reset {\n    \n    margin: 0;\n" +
                "    \n}\n\n.reset.slass {\n    \n    padding-top: 10px;\n    \n}\n\n#fixedbs {\n    \n    text-align: center;\n    position: absolute;\n    top: 118px;\n    left: 80px;\n " +
                "   color: black;\n    \n}";

            string html = String.Format("<!doctype html>\n\n<html lang=\"en\">\n    \n<head>\n    \n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n\n    <style>{0}</style>\n\n</head>\n\n<body>\n    \n    <div id=\"window\">\n" +
                "        \n        <div id=\"header\">\n        \n            <div id=\"pfp\">\n\n                <img src=\"\"> <!-- Insert source of Profile picture -->\n\n            </div>\n\n" +
                "            <div id=\"userwindow\"> <!-- This is where you want to input stats -->\n\n                <p class=\"reset user\"><b>Username#1234</b></p>\n " +
                "               <p class=\"reset user\">Some other stat lol</p>\n                <p class=\"reset user\">Lifetime Gambles: <b>###</b></p>\n\n            </div>\n            \n" +
                "        </div>\n        \n        <div id=\"content\">\n        \n            <div id=\"probox\">\n            \n                <div id=\"probar\"></div> <!-- Progress bar percentage is in CSS -->\n" +
                "                \n                <p id=\"fixedbs\">cur lvl prog / total lvl exp</p>\n                \n            </div>\n            \n            <div id=\"rows\">\n " +
                "           \n                <div id=\"exp\">\n\n                    <div id=\"lvl\"> <!-- This is where you want to input Level -->\n\n                        <p class=\"reset\">Level</p>\n" +
                "                        <p class=\"reset no\"><b>12</b></p>\n\n                    </div>\n\n                    <div id=\"rep\"> <!-- This is where you want to input Rep -->\n\n" +
                "                        <p class=\"reset\">Rep +<b>0</b> </p>\n\n                    </div>\n\n                </div>\n\n                <div id=\"statsl\">\n\n" +
                "                    <p class=\"reset slass\">Total EXP</p>\n                    <p class=\"reset slass\">Server Rank</p>\n                    <p class=\"reset slass\">Global Rank</p>\n" +
                "                    <p class=\"reset slass\">Points</p>            \n\n                </div>\n\n                <div id=\"statsr\"> <!-- This is where you want to input stats -->\n\n " +
                "                   <p class=\"reset slass\">####</p>\n                    <p class=\"reset slass\">#123</p>\n                    <p class=\"reset slass\">#1234</p>\n" +
                "                    <p class=\"reset slass\">####</p>            \n\n                </div>\n            \n            </div>\n            \n            <div id=\"footer\">\n" +
                "                \n                <div id=\"leftfoot\">\n            \n                    <p class=\"reset\">Average Win Percantage</p>\n                    <p class=\"reset\">Chance of Elite+ Roll</p>\n" +
                "                    \n                </div>\n                \n                <div id=\"rightfoot\"> <!-- This is where you want to input stats -->\n" +
                "                \n                    <p class=\"reset\">###%</p>\n                    <p class=\"reset\">###%</p>\n                    \n" +
                "                </div>\n                \n            </div>\n            \n        </div>\n        \n    </div>\n    \n</body>\n    \n</html>", css);
            var converter = new HtmlToImageConverter
            {
                Width = 300,
                Height = 320
            };
            var pngBytes = converter.GenerateImage(html, NReco.ImageGenerator.ImageFormat.Png);
            await Context.Channel.SendFileAsync(new MemoryStream(pngBytes), "Profile.png");
        }
```

Original HTML

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>discord thing</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

</head>

<body> 

    <div id="window">

        <div id="header">

            <div id="pfp"></div>

            <p id="name"><b>Garonen#6115</b></p>

        </div>

        <div id="content">

            <div id="probox">

                <div id="probar"></div>

                <p id="fixedbs">cur lvl prog / total lvl exp</p>

            </div>

            <div id="row">

                <div class="inforow" id="level">

                    <p id="yes">Level</p>
                    <p id="no"><b>11</b></p>

                </div>

                <div class="inforow" id="infolist">
                    <p class="info">Total EXP</p>
                    <p class="info">Server Rank</p>
                    <p class="info">Global Rank</p>
                </div>

                <div class="inforow" id="statlist">
                    <p class="info">xxxxEXP</p>
                    <p class="info">#xxxx</p>
                    <p class="info">#xxxx</p>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>  

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Original CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  src: URL('Raleway-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}

html {

    margin: 0px;

}
body {

    margin: 0px;

}

#window {

    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'Raleway';

}

#header {

    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    display: flex;

}

#pfp {

    border: solid 3px black;
    flex-grow: 1;

}

#userwindow {

    border: solid 3px black;
    flex-grow: 0.352;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;

}

.reset.user {

    padding-bottom: 8px;

}

#content {

    border: solid 3px black;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    margin-top: 10px;

}

#probox {

    height: 18px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    padding: 1px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;

}

#probar {

    height: 100%;
    width: 50%; /* Insert EXP progress in percent here */
    background-color: #7FDCFF;

}

#rows {

    display: flex;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

}

#exp {

    flex-grow: 1;

}

#lvl {

    font-size: 25px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;

}

.reset.no {

    font-size: 45px;

}

#rep {

    text-align: center;

}

#statsl {

    flex-grow: 1;

}

#statsr {

    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 22px;

}

#footer {

    display: flex;
    border-top: solid black 2px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 85%;
```

**For the result, we are expecting this output:

[image]

Currently, we are getting this output:

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's grabbing a bit more of the page than you wanted.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I really have no idea what the converter is doing that is making the image's text go all over the place like it is, and it looks like the box for the profile picture (top left) is squished to the left..On the HTML page it's perfect, but using the image generator, it causes these distortions.

Comment: Does the HTML and CSS you posted work the same way in all of the major browsers?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, we've tested on all major browsers and get the same output.